# Folder contents listing batch script

Tags: batch-file

I would like help with a batch script that will list all files in a folder and its sub folders to run as a scheduled task.

Thanks in advance and best regards to all.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: It is unclear what exactly you are asking for. Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

If I got it right, you want to run a Batch file that displays the Files on a folder (including  files in subfolders) as a scheduled task:

```
@echo off
DIR <directory of the folder, i.e "c:\dell\drivers\*.*"> /s
pause
```

I don't get why would you want to schedule this kind of task, but Dir lists the files with some info and the /s arg adds the files contained in subfolders.

Cheers!
[P.S. sorry if that wasn't what you wanted, it is hard to understand]

Answer (score -1):

Like this?

```
@echo off

dir /S > list.txt

pause
```